# Print PDF with page numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple excel sheets and these need to be printed into one single PDF document. Some sheets have multiple pages and some sheets only one page.

I've written a VBA to print these sheets to PDF and it works pretty good. However I would like to add pagenumers to these pages that match the PDF pages. But I can't get it working.. Does anyone know how to add this to my code?

```
 Sub PrintFS()

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("1. Front Sheet", "2. Page", "3. Page", "4. Page", "5. Page", "6. Page")).Select

 'Set PDF Name     
 TemplatePath = Left(Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\")), InStrRev(Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\")), "\"))
 Entity = Worksheets("Topsheet").Range("B2").Value
 Year2day = Worksheets("Topsheet").Range("B3").Value

 'Print PDF    
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
TemplatePath & "\Accounts - " & Year2day & " - " & Entity & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you add the page number and total pages in original workbook in footer/header? There is no need of VBA to do that

Comment: yes I agree with Foxfire And Burns And Burns.
@ErikSlui: in case you do not know how to implement the suggested solution, go to Insert tab > in Text group, click on Header & Footer > select where you want the text (in your case the page number) to appear > type the text

Comment: Aah great! That works perfectly. Sometimes an easy fix is the best fix.. Thanks a lot!